# Loading text file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a comma separated file with 182 rows and 501 columns, of which 500 columns are of type number (features) while the last column are strings (labels).

Example: 182x501 dimension

```
1,3,4,6,.........7, ABC
4,5,6,4,.........9, XYZ
3,4,5,3,.........2, ABC
```

How can I load this file so it will have a data set with a matrix, `B`, containing the number as my features, and a vector, `C`, containing the strings as my labels?

```
d = dataset(B, C);
```

Answer (score 4):

Build a format specifier for textscan based on the number and types of columns, and have it read the file for you.

```
nNumberCols = 500;
format = [repmat('%f,', [1 nNumberCols]) '%s'];
fid = fopen(file);
x = textscan(fid, format);
fclose(fid);
B = cat(2, x{1:nNumberCols});
C = x{end};
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [textscan](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) function. For example:

```
fid = fopen('test.dat');

% Read numbers and string into a cell array
data = textscan(fid, '%s %s');

% Then extract the numbers and strings into their own cell arrays
nums = data{1};
str  = data{2};

% Convert string of numbers to numbers
for i = 1:length(str)
    nums{i} = str2num(nums{i}); %#ok<ST2NM>
end

% Finally, convert cell array of numbers to a matrix
nums = cell2mat(nums);

fclose(fid);
```

Note that I have made a number of assumptions here, based on the file format you have specified. For example, I assume that there are no spaces after the commas following a number, but that there is a space immediately preceding the string at the end of each line.

To can make the above code more flexible by using a more considered format specifier (the second argument to `textscan`). See the section `Basic Conversion Specifiers` in the `textscan` documentation.

Answer (score 3):

For example, if you have the following data in a file named `data.txt`:

```
1,3,4,6,7, ABC
4,5,6,4,9, XYZ
3,4,5,3,2, ABC
```

you can read it into a matrix `B` and a cell array `C` using the code

```
N = 5; % Number of numeric data to read
fid = fopen('data.txt');
B = []; C = {};
while ~feof(fid)  % repeat until end of file is reached
  b = fscanf(fid, '%f,', N); % read N numeric data separated by a comma
  c = fscanf(fid, '%s', 1);  % read a string
  B = [B, b];
  C = [C, c];
end
C
B
fclose(fid);
```

to give

```
C = 
  'ABC'    'XYZ'    'ABC'
B =
 1     4     3
 3     5     4
 4     6     5
 6     4     3
 7     9     2
```

Comment: I think you have an error at `C=[C,c]`... It should probably either be `C={C,c}` or, more likely, something like `C(end+1)={c}`. I don't remember the exact syntax, sorry.

Comment: @eykanal. It is not an error. Array concatenation operator `[]` works for cell arrays as well, as you can confirm using `C = {};c = 'a';C = [C, c], C = [C, c]'.

Comment: You mean `c={'a'}; c=[c c];`, but yeah, I just tested it, you're right.